# Separate domain for separate apps on django

Tags: django

I'd like to separate some apps on my website, and move some on differents domains.

But I'd like to avoid rewriting the urls in all the templates.

Is there an easy way to do this ?

Comment: you dont have to rewrite urls in templates if you use `{% url "url_name" %}` ;)

Comment: but then, how do i create urls.py files that say that those apps are on different domains ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea was to rewrite the reverse function (and thus, all the url dispatching thing).

Then, you have the first website called '**foo.com**' and the second named **'bar.com**'

This works for more sites than just two

**app/urls.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from foo import urls as foo_urls
from bar import urls as bar_urls

url_patterns = [
    url(r'^foo/',
        include(foo_urls),
        namespace='foo'),
    url(r'^bar/',
        include(bar_urls),
        namespace='bar'),
    ]
```

**app/__init__.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8
"""
Just to simplify the multi website thing. Everything is served from one instance
"""
from __future__ import absolute_import
from django.core import urlresolvers
from django.http import Http404

from .settings LANGUAGES


old_reverse = urlresolvers.reverse


def remove_prefix(s, prefix):
    return s[len(prefix):] if s.startswith(prefix) else s


def new_reverse(viewname, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None, current_app=None):
    """ Return an url with the domain if the page is situated on another domain
    Note that this works for urls templatetags and for 
    django.core.urlresolvers.reverse, that are used a lot in get_absolute_url()
    methods.
    """
    old_reverse_url = old_reverse(viewname, urlconf, args, kwargs, current_app)
    splitted_url = old_reverse_url.split('/')
    if splitted_url[1] in [L[0] for L in LANGUAGES]:
        (trash, lang, app, *path) = splitted_url
    else:
        (trash, app, *path) = splitted_url
        lang = ''
    if app == 'admin' or current_app == 'admin':
        # fix a case where sometime the reverse has or has not a trailing /
        old_reverse_url = remove_prefix(old_reverse_url, '/')
        # fix a case where sometime the reverse has a double admin at the
        # begining
        old_reverse_url = old_reverse_url.replace('adminadmin', 'admin')
        return '/%s' % old_reverse_url
    path = '/'.join(path)
    if lang ==  '':
        return '//%s.com/%s' % (app, path)
    else:
        return '//%s.com/%s/%s' % (app, lang, path)


urlresolvers.reverse = new_reverse
```

**templates examples**

```
<a href="{% url 'foo:index' %}*>foo index</a>
```